# SQLAlchemy add row index to response

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using an SQLAlchemy query to order a `User` table based on their summed score in another table to display a scoreboard, with the following query:

```
session.query(User, func.sum(Question.points)).join(Answer, User.id == Answer.user_id).join(Question, Answer.Question_id == Question.id).group_by(User.id).order_by(func.sum(Question.points).desc()).all()
```

Which returns data as I expect in the following manner:

```
<User object 1> 500
<User object 2> 300
<User object 3> 100
```

I am then doing "post-processing" on this returned data in `python` to add their ranking:

```
1 <User object 1> 500
2 <User object 2> 300
3 <User object 3> 100
```

Is there a way to include the ranking in the response returned from SQLAlchemy without needing the extra post-processing step?